# Get-child item Lastwritetime is not returning properly

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to get the `CreationTime` and `Lastwritetime` using `get-childitem` command and comparing it with the same assembly time to check if there is any difference for every 5 minutes.

Strangely there is a difference in milliseconds for every time when I fetch the records if the assembly did not change and it is causing the compare-object to fail.

Is there any way to fix this, other than converting the time to string format?

below is the command to fetch the details of the Assemblies

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL' -include *.dll -Recurse|select @{Label=”AssemblyName”;Expression={$_.Name}},@{Label=”Size”; Expression={$_.Length}},@{label="Version";expression={if($_.versioninfo.productversion -eq $null) { 
              "NULL"
            } else { 
              $_.versioninfo.productversion
            }
          }},@{Label=”CreationTime”; Expression={$_.CreationTime}},@{Label=”LastWriteTimeUtc”; Expression={$_.LastWriteTimeUtc}}
```

and running this command after 5 minutes and comparing with compare-object

```
compare-object -$oldobject $newObject -property Name,Lastwritetime
```

Comment: What do you mean? What causes `Compare-Object` to fail? You need to post a specific and concrete example and explain what you want to do. (Remember that nobody can see your screen. You must explain all details. Don't make people guess.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : edited the question with the example

Comment: One thing to note is that you have `$.somepropertyname` in many places in your code, which should be replaced with `$_.somepropertyname`.

Also note that Compare-Object will fail a comparison if the value is $NULL. You may want to change your results in those instances to an empty string to avoid the cmdlet breaking, or adding is a `try{} catch [Exception]{}` block to handle instances where you have null results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the exact reasons why there is a difference of some milliseconds (most probably an [inaccurate floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)).

The usual solution for a problem like this is to use an [epsilon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon(v=vs.110).aspx) value in your comparisons (pretty common in game programming among others).

```
Set-Variable -name EPSILON -value ([double]0.00001) #-option Constant
function Is-Same {
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [double]$a,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [double]$b
    )
    #return $a - $b;
    return [math]::abs($a - $b) -le $EPSILON;
}

Is-Same 1.000001 1.0000
Is-Same 1.00001 1.0000
Is-Same 1.0001 1.0000
```

> True
>   False
>   False

Adjust the epsilon value as needed. (adhering numerical limits)